# Select document in a view from another with with Lotus notes @formula

Tags: lotus-notes

there is a method using lotus notes @formula to recover a value contained in a view (view1) to use it in the selection formula of another view(view2) ?

View1 contain only ONE column and ONE document.
i try with:

w:=@dbcolumn("","NoCache";server;db;"view1",1)

and also:

w:=@dbcolumn("","NoCache";server;db;"view1","FieldName")

but these formula retrieve NUll value.
i think's i can't use @dblookup formula because i don't have the "Key" value for the search.

thank's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to do.

This is detailed in the actual commands help.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DBCOLUMN_NOTES_DATABASES.html

> Usage @DbColumn is intended mainly for use with keyword formulas.
>   Instead of hard-coding a list of keywords and then periodically
>   updating that list by re-editing the form containing the keyword
>   field, @DbColumn allows you to dynamically retrieve a list of values
>   from a database view or table.
>
> **This function does not work in column or selection formulas, or in
>   mail agents**.

Any kind of dynamic data in the view selection should be avoided.

What happens is the View indexer (NIF) will check to see if the View Selection formula equates to the current NIF state.

If you have dynamic data then the NIF can continually refresh over and over, causing performance and other issues in the view. You can reproduce this by using @Today, @Tomorrow, (etc) functions in the view selection.

Apart from that reason, there is an overhead in @DBColumn that would make the view indexer usage unfeasible even if you could get it to work.